# Background login and retrieve info from a third-party website

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a web system using HTML and JavaScript, and I need to show in my site some users' info which can be accessed only by logging in to a third-party system.

Here is what their login form looks like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="Welcome">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirpage" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirparam" id="redirparam" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="flogontext" value="User logon">
  <input type="hidden" name="fpwdtext" value="PIN code">
  <input type="hidden" name="flogonEnc" id="flogonEnc" value="">
  <div class="login_form_element">
     <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
        <div class="login_field_user_box">
           <div class="logon_field_lbl" id="lblUserLogon" onclick="field_focus(flogon)">User logon</div>
           <input class="login_field_input" type="text" name="flogon" id="flogon" maxlength="254" size="24" value="">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="login_form_element">
     <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
        <div class="logon_field_lbl_pwd" id="lblPassword" onclick="field_focus(fpwd)">PIN code</div>
        <input class="login_field_password_input" type="password" name="fpwd" id="fpwd" maxlength="4" value="">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="login_form_element"><input id="btnloginsubmit" class="rounded_login_btn" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
```

I know that I will have problems with cross-origin request, so I intend to use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a proxy.

Yes, I have a working login to enter on their website, but the problem is that I've tried many things to do this in the background, and I couldn't login anyway.

I tried using postman to test requests, but it didn't work either.

Just in case their website is [here](https://secure.ditprint.ie/safecom/webuser.dll/login).

Comment: What have you tried? You need to use Fetch or XHR or some Ajax method from a JavaScript library to send a POST request to `https://secure.ditprint.ie/safecom/webuser.dll/login` with `flogon=<NAME>&fpwd=<PIN>` as the body of the request

Comment: @sideshowbarker I will take a look about this.

Comment: @Kamil your answer helped me, and I already clicked up arrow to you. Thanks. I will come back with updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you will need to write your own cors proxy-server (e.g. in php - it is not difficult) because https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ will be not not enough. However try this (I copy `<form>` from your [login site](https://secure.ditprint.ie/safecom/webuser.dll/login), and change `<form>` action to send similar request like source site - but I don't have any login/PIN to test this)

```html
<div class="login_inner_container">
   <h2>Please sign in</h2>
   <form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://secure.ditprint.ie/safecom/webuser.dll/Welcome">
      <input type="hidden" name="redirpage" value=""><input type="hidden" name="redirparam" id="redirparam" value=""><input type="hidden" name="flogontext" value="User logon"><input type="hidden" name="fpwdtext" value="PIN code"><input type="hidden" name="flogonEnc" id="flogonEnc" value="">
      <div class="login_form_element">
         <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
            <div class="login_field_user_box">
               <div class="logon_field_lbl" id="lblUserLogon" onclick="field_focus(flogon)">User logon</div>
               <input class="login_field_input" type="text" name="flogon" id="flogon" maxlength="254" size="24" value="">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login_form_element">
         <div class="login_field_user_box_border">
            <div class="logon_field_lbl_pwd" id="lblPassword" onclick="field_focus(fpwd)">PIN code</div>
            <input class="login_field_password_input" type="password" name="fpwd" id="fpwd" maxlength="4" value="">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login_form_element"><input id="btnloginsubmit" class="rounded_login_btn" type="submit" value="Login"></div>
   </form>
   <div id="sysloginmsg" class="login_message_error_hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! it really worked to login in. Now what I really want is kind of "navigate" on their  website on the background of my system to get the information that I need. (e.g. login/ home/ documents/ etc). How can I make the http requests on the background of my system and deal with this?

Comment: this is separate question - ask it on StackOverflow (and describre details)

Comment: Yeah. You helped me with my mistake on the action method. But now there is a whole question about sending and treating http requests. Thank you.